# Is there any way to split gcc macro arguments?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I write code that can run on GPU or CPU. In case of CUDA presence wrapper try to run function on GPU. In case of error (no memory for example) it try to run it on CPU. In case of error again it returns 0, otherwise it returns 1.
In case of CUDA absence wrapper only try to run function on CPU.

Here is my macro:

```
#ifdef CUDA_FOUND
#define SET_F(FNARGS, FNSTRIP) int FNARGS{  \
    if(!Only_CPU) if(CU ## FNSTRIP) return 1;\
    if(CPU ## FNSTRIP) return 1;            \
    return 0;                               \
}
#else
#define SET_F(FNARGS, FNSTRIP) int FNARGS{  \
    if(CPU ## FNSTRIP) return 1;            \
    return 0;                               \
}
#endif // CUDA_FOUND
```

To define new function I call it so:

```
SET_F(fillrandarr(size_t sz, char *arr), fillrandarr(sz, arr))
```

**Question**: is there a way to simplify this macro splitting arguments of `FNARGS` to compose `FNSTRIP`? I.e. to shorten the definition above to

```
SET_F(fillrandarr(size_t sz, char *arr))
```

?

Comment: I expect you will use this macro for more functions then the one you posted. Will all of them have exactly two parameters?

Comment: There would be a lot of functions and amount of their parameters differs from one function to another. The only common thing in them is that they return `int`.

Comment: The Boost preprocessor library probably can do this.

Comment: "Boost preprocessor library"? In C?

Comment: Boost is generally C++, but the preprocessor library is just a set of macros, with no (as far as I know) C++-specific parts.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include your own solution, you should rather write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4):

As n.m. wrote in his comments:

> The Boost preprocessor library probably can do this.
>   Boost is generally C++, but the preprocessor library is just a set of macros, with no (as far as I know) C++-specific parts.

So here is a boost-ish solution:

```
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS 1

#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define FOO(...) FOO2(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
#define FOO2(seq) FOO3(BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(seq),BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(seq))
#define FOO3(name, args) FOO6(name,                                \
                              BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(FOO4,,args), \
                              BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(FOO5,,args))
#define FOO4(rep, data, index, type) (type BOOST_PP_CAT(arg,index))
#define FOO5(rep, data, index, type) (BOOST_PP_CAT(arg,index))
#define FOO6(name, dargs, cargs)                                   \
  FOO8(name, FOO7(dargs, void), FOO7(cargs, ))
#define FOO7(seq, empty)                                           \
  BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(seq),                              \
              BOOST_PP_SEQ_TO_TUPLE(seq), (empty))
#define FOO8(name, dargs, cargs)                                   \
  int name dargs {                                                 \
    if (BOOST_PP_CAT(CPU_, name)cargs)                             \
      return 1;                                                    \
    return 0;                                                      \
  }

FOO(fillrandarr, size_t, char*)
FOO(fun1, int, double)
FOO(fun2)
```

It generates code like this (formatting added by me):

```
int fillrandarr (size_t arg0, char* arg1) {
  if (CPU_fillrandarr(arg0, arg1))
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

int fun1 (int arg0, double arg1) {
  if (CPU_fun1(arg0, arg1))
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

int fun2 (void) {
  if (CPU_fun2())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

I omitted the names  of the arguments from the macro call, as they are practically of no imprtance. Special care has been taken to handle that last case, of a function with no arguments, correctly in the same framework.

Here are the different steps:

1. As variadic macros apparently cannot distinguish between zero arguments and one single empty argument, the very first macro which always includes the function name will have to turn the variadic arguments into a more easily handled data structure, in this case a sequence of parenthesized expressions.
2. Next we split that sequence into the function name and the argument types.
3. We convert the argument type sequence into two sequences, one for function definition and the other for function call.
4. For function definition, we prefix each argument name with its type.
5. For function call, we ignore the type and simply write the numbered argument name.
6. Next we have to make sure we treat empty sequence correctly. For call we can simply write `()` but for function definition we have to write `(void)` instead.
7. So we check to see whether the sequence has non-zero size. If so, we convert it to a tuple, i.e. commas between and parentheses around elements. Otherwise we use the provided default.
8. Now we combine everything the way you requested.

Comment: It's interesting. But I have a few questions: 1) will this work for example with gcc-none-eaby? 2) Is there a short manual about boost preprocessor directives?

Comment: @Eddy_Em: I don't know what you mean by “gcc-none-eaby”. Please explain that. In general, boost is highly tuned for portability with various common compilers, and the headers contain many case distinctions to work around compiler-specific oddities. So using boost will likely be far more portable than implementing things directly. See for example the special case for MSVC in [variadic argument counting](http://tinyurl.com/akpoqph). For manuals, see [the docs](http://tinyurl.com/ajccant) and in particular the reference there.

Comment: I mean compiler for non-x86 processors.

Comment: @Eddy_Em, the processor architecture should be pretty much irrelevant to the preprocessor, so I see no problems there. The above code uses variadic macros, and in cases where these are not available, you'd have to change the first few macros and the way the top macro gets invoked, e.g. to `FOO(2,fun1,(int,double))`. But most compilers should be capable of using variadic macros. In my boost version, the number of arguments supported appears to be 64, including the function name.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare wrapper macros around the one you already have for functions using a different number of parameters:

```
#define SET_F_2(fname, \
  vtype1, vname1, \
  vtype2, vname2 \
) \
  SET_F( \
    fname( \
      vtype1 vname1, \
      vtype2 vname2 \
    ), \
    fname( \
      vname1, \
      vname2 \
    ) \
)

#define SET_F_3(fname, \
  vtype1, vname1, \
  vtype2, vname2, \
  vtype3, vname3 \
) \
  SET_F( \
    fname( \
      vtype1 vname1, \
      vtype2 vname2, \
      vtype3 vname3 \
    ), \
    fname( \
      vname1, \
      vname2, \
      vname3 \
    ) \
)

... and so on
```

Use it like this:

```
SET_F_2(x, short, s, int, i);
SET_F_3(y, int, i, short, s, float, f);
```

This approach might surely be optimized for less redundancy using [*slartibartfast*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289766/slartibartfast) [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354274/694576) for counting a `#define`'s number of parameters.

Comment: That's a very bulky construction. Also some my functions have up to 5-7 arguments! But idea is good. Thank you. BTW there's no use to write variables names in macros SET_F_X: they could be set by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take apart preprocessing symbols with the preprocessor, you can only combine them. This means that "fillrandarr(sz,arr)" is one atomic unit for the preprocessor and therefore not what will fit your needs. You will have to pass the symbols separated in a parameter list, like

```
#define SET_F(f_name,p1_type,p1_name,p2_type,p2_name) ...
```

For the variable amount of parameters going into the functions use

```
#define CNT_ARGS(...) CNT_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
#define CNT_ARGS_(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,n) n

#define DROP_TYPE(...) DROP_TYPE_(CNT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__),__VA_ARGS__)
#define DROP_TYPE_(n,...) DROP_TYPE__(n,__VA_ARGS__)
#define DROP_TYPE__(n,...) DROP_TYPE_##n(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DROP_TYPE_2(ptype,pname,...) pname
#define DROP_TYPE_4(ptype,pname,...) pname, DROP_TYPE_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DROP_TYPE_6(ptype,pname,...) pname, DROP_TYPE_4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DROP_TYPE_8(ptype,pname,...) pname, DROP_TYPE_6(__VA_ARGS__)


#define FOO(fname,...)  fname(DROP_TYPE(__VA_ARGS__))

    FOO(my_func,t1,p1,t2,p2,t3,p3,t4,p4)  -> my_func(p1,p2,p3,p4)
    FOO(other_func,t1,p1,t2,p2)           -> other_func(p1,p2)
```

Comment: Hehe, that's step 1. Are you sure the remaining steps are possible?

Comment: I thought about it, but I couldn't think of how to parse variable arguments so that in one case they are groups in pair and in other there are only odd of them.

Answer (score 1):

After all I did next things (up to 10 arguments):

```
#define Fn1(A,B) A(x1)
#define Df1(A,B) A(B x1)
#define Fn2(A,B,C) A(x1, x2)
#define Df2(A,B,C) A(B x1, C x2)
#define Fn3(A,B,C,D) A(x1, x2, x3)
#define Df3(A,B,C,D) A(B x1, C x2, D x3)
#define Fn4(A,B,C,D,E) A(x1, x2, x3, x4)
#define Df4(A,B,C,D,E) A(B x1, C x2, D x3, E x4)
#define Fn5(A,B,C,D,E,F) A(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
#define Df5(A,B,C,D,E,F) A(B x1, C x2, D x3, E x4, F x5)
#define Fn6(A,B,C,D,E,F,G) A(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6)
#define Df6(A,B,C,D,E,F,G) A(B x1, C x2, D x3, E x4, F x5, G x6)
#define Fn7(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) A(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
#define Df7(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) A(B x1, C x2, D x3, E x4, F x5, G x6, H x7)
#define Fn8(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I) A(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8)
#define Df8(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I) A(B x1, C x2, D x3, E x4, F x5, G x6, H x7, I x8)
#define Fn9(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J) A(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9)
#define Df9(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J) A(B x1, C x2, D x3, E x4, F x5, G x6, H x7, I x8, J x9)
#define Fn10(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K) A(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)
#define Df10(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K) A(B x1, C x2, D x3, E x4, F x5, G x6, H x7, I x8, J x9, K x10)

#define DEF(N, ...) int Df ## N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CONCAT(A, B) A ## B
#define FN(N, ...) Fn ## N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DF(N, ...) Df ## N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define XFUNC(T, X) CONCAT(T, X)
#define FUNC(T, ...) XFUNC(T, FN(__VA_ARGS__))
#define DFUNC(T,...) EXTERN int XFUNC(T, DF(__VA_ARGS__))

#ifdef WRAPPER_C
// even when using cuda in case of fail CUDA init use CPU
static int Only_CPU =
#ifdef CUDA_FOUND
    0
#else
    1
#endif
;
#ifdef CUDA_FOUND
#define SET_F(...) DEF(__VA_ARGS__){                    \
    if(!Only_CPU) if(FUNC(CU, __VA_ARGS__)) return 1;   \
    if(FUNC(CPU, __VA_ARGS__)) return 1;                \
    return 0;                                           \
}
#else
#define SET_F(...) DEF(__VA_ARGS__){                    \
    if(FUNC(CPU, __VA_ARGS__)) return 1;                \
    return 0;                                           \
}
#endif // CUDA_FOUND
#else
    #define SET_F(...)
#endif // WRAPPER_C

#ifdef CPU_C // file included from CPU.c
    #define BOTH(...) DFUNC(CPU, __VA_ARGS__);
    //#pragma message "CPUC"
#elif defined CUDA_CU //file included from CUDA.cu
    #define BOTH(...) DFUNC(CU, __VA_ARGS__);
#elif defined WRAPPER_C // wrapper.c needs names of both wariants
    #ifndef CUDA_FOUND
        #define BOTH(...) DFUNC(CPU, __VA_ARGS__);
    #else
        #define BOTH(...) DFUNC(CU, __VA_ARGS__); DFUNC(CPU, __VA_ARGS__);
    #endif // CUDA_FOUND
#else // file included from something else - just define a function
    #define BOTH(...) DFUNC(, __VA_ARGS__);
#endif

#define DFN(...) BOTH(__VA_ARGS__) SET_F(__VA_ARGS__)
```

This code is in file wrapper.h. wrapper.c consist only a common part of code.

To define functions I write in wrapper.h something like:

```
DFN(2, fillrandarr, size_t, float *)
DFN(6, bicubic_interp, float *, float *, size_t, size_t, size_t, size_t)
```